# ERROR in Cannot find module 'babel-core'. using react.js, webpack, and express server

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Whenever I run `webpack` in the terminal I get:

```
Hash: efea76b1048c3a97b963
Version: webpack 1.12.13
Time: 33ms
    + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in Cannot find module 'babel-core'
```

Here is my **webpack.config.js** file

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app-client.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'public/bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /(node_modules|app-server.js)/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React polling app",
  "main": "app-client.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "react": "^0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 156):

You should install babel-loader and babel-core as dev-dependency while npm install.

```
npm install babel-core babel-loader --save-dev
```

Comment: worked like a charm! rember to add it to your `packag.json` to avoid facing this problem again. Running `npm install ` with flag `-S` wiil do the job.

Comment: I'm still getting: `Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
babel-loader@8 requires Babel 7.x (the package '@babel/core'). If you'd like to use Babel 6.x ('babel-core'), you should install 'babel-loader@7'`

Comment: It seems like loader v8 needs core v7, but core v7 currently just has a `beta` release, which seems like an oversight from the maintainers.  I manually specified `7.1.5` for `babel-loader` (the latest version that is out right now) and I'm off and running

Answer (score 47):

For those wanting to use babel-loader 8+: it requires Babel 7.x,, which is to be installed as the '@babel/core' package instead of 'babel-core'.
In other words, run:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core
```

Comment: Then I guess you aren't using babel-loader 8+. I answered this for people who happen to be upgrading/starting a new project but don't realize why it isn't working because of package rename.
No need to downvote while it's clearly stated what version it applies to.

Answer (score 13):

I just meet this error, and solved by installing babel-core.
But the interesting is I found babel-core does exist in babel-loader's peerDependencies.

https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/blob/master/package.json

Why peerDependecies not install automatically, after a few searching work I found [this](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5) in npm blog.

peerDependencies will not automatically install anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to @Chetan's answer on this thread:

I ran into this issue today while following through Dr. Axel Rauschmayer's book [here](https://leanpub.com/setting-up-es6/read#leanpub-auto-using-ecmascript-6-today). Per book, `babel-loader` should download `babel-core` as well. However this is not the case when I tried it out. I think this relates to @theJian's answer.

Since the original package.json already lists `babel-loader` as dependency, running the following command resolved the error.

```
npm install babel-core --save-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

```
npm install babel-register
```

This can solve your issue. Additionally, add babelrc 
    .babelrc
    {
        "presets" : ["es2015", "react"]
    }

Comment: Why? Can you give some explanation as to why this would work?