# Error in setting up ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, webpack

i am new to reactJs and setting up the environment for reactJs application. I have package,json file like this

```
{
 "name": "reactjs-basics",
  "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "Some basic ReactJS",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
 "start": "npm run build",
 "build": "webpack -d && copy src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-
  server --content-base src/ --inline --hot",
"build:prod": "webpack -p && copy src/index.html dist/index.html"
        },
 "keywords": [
 "reactjs"
      ],
 "author": "Maximilian Schwarzmueller",
 "license": "MIT",
 "dependencies": {
 "react": "^15.2.1",
"react-dom": "^15.2.1"
     },
"devDependencies": {
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.11.0",
"webpack": "^1.13.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
    }
 }
```

and web.config.js file like this

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require("path");

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
output: {
    path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/app/"
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js?/,
            include: SRC_DIR,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
                presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
            }
        }
    ]
  }
 };
```

module.exports = config;

when i am running this command "npm start" then i am getting this error

```
"ERROR in Cannot find module 'babel-core'
 The syntax of the command is incorrect.

 npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
 npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program  
 Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
 npm ERR! node v6.10.0
 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build: `webpack -d && copy src/index.html 
 dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build script 'webpack -d && 
 copy src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base 
 src/ --inline --hot'.
 npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm 
 installed.
 npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactjs-basics 
 package,
 npm ERR! not with npm itself.
 npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 npm ERR!     webpack -d && copy src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack- 
 dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot
 npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
 with:
 npm ERR!     npm bugs reactjs-basics
 npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
 npm ERR!     npm owner ls reactjs-basics
 npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 npm ERR!     C:\Users\fahad\Downloads\reactjs-basics-master\reactjs-basics- 
 master\npm-debug.log

 npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
 npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
 Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
 npm ERR! node v6.10.0
 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start: `npm run build`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start script 'npm run build'.
 npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm 
 installed.
 npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactjs-basics 
 package,
 npm ERR! not with npm itself.
 npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 npm ERR!     npm run build
 npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
 with:
 npm ERR!     npm bugs reactjs-basics
 npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
 npm ERR!     npm owner ls reactjs-basics
 npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 npm ERR!     C:\Users\fahad\Downloads\reactjs-basics-master\reactjs-basics- 
 master\npm-debug.log"
```

How can i solve this? i don' know why this is throwing an error please review this and let me know what is the error exactly.

Comment: try `npm install` first?

Comment: i tried npm install, npm install babel-core --save-dev. but still getting errors which i mentioned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR in Cannot find module 'babel-core'. using react.js, webpack, and express server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215461/error-in-cannot-find-module-babel-core-using-react-js-webpack-and-express-s)

Comment: @MayankShukla there is no solution to work for me.

Comment: @FahadSubzwari can you check your `node_modules` folder, whether `babel-core`  installed properly?

Comment: thanx but i solved it bro :)

Comment: If you solved it, you should mention your solution for the benefit of others who may have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "/", use "\" in your `webpack.config.js`.

It worked using this:

```
"build": "webpack -d && copy src\\index.html dist\\index.html && webpack-dev-
server --content-base src/ --inline --hot"
```